# find distance in line-circle intersection

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, intersection

A line intersects a circle with center in `C (cx,cy)` and radius `r`. The line is described by a position `P (px, py)` and a direction `D (dx, dy)`. `P` lies inside the circle and the line is infinitely long. What's the distance `d` from `P` to the point of intersection?

```
float Intersect(Vector2d C, float r, Vector2d P, Vector2d D){

    ...

    return d;
}
```

Comment: You could transform C to the origin and apply the formulas from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(Euclidean_geometry)#A_line_and_a_circle) to get the intersection point I. Then compute the distance between I and P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand parentheses and solve quadratic equation for unknown `t`:

```
((px - cx) + t * dx)^2 + ((py - cy) + t * dy)^2 = r^2
```

If `(dx,dy)` vector is normalized (unit length), then value of `t` (positive root if your line is really  ray starting inside a circle) is needed distance.

Formula for intersection point (is not needed in current statement)

```
ix = px + t * dx
iy = py + t * dy
```